# Escaping special characters while inserting in mysql

Tags: mysql, escaping, mysql-real-escape-string

I am inserting multi-rows in a mysql database by concating values as in the query

```
INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2, col3) VALUES('a', 'b', 'c'), ('d', 'b', 'c'), ('e', 'b', 'c');
```

However, sometimes some of the values of the entire bunch needs to be escaped, like I got `s-â€__83164` as one of my values to enter. This causes the entire bunch of request to drop when only one or two of the values are faulty.

Is there any way to escape characters like `s-â€__83164` or do I need a modification in the type of field, I am using for it. I am currently using `VARCHAR` for storing those values.

Please comment if I am unclear in asking my doubt !

Comment: here your values are dynamic?

Comment: Yeah , they are dynamic and unpredicatble

Answer (score 0):

One thing that you can do, is get all characters into variables and then place those variables in your SQL query. While declaring the variable you can use single quotes to include your data.